# Can't connect to sql server via Sequel Pro on digital ocean

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

I want to connect to my database server, hosted on digital ocean. Therefore I configured my Sequel Pro setup like this:

[image]

The error I get is:

[image]

on my server the port 3306 is allowed via `ufw allow 3306/tcp' and the ufw service has been restarted. Still I cannot connect. I am asked for my password for the SSH service, which works, but then the error arises. Where do I need to reconfigure my settings?

Comment: Just wondering if you've got any update on this? Facing the same problem now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the current `MySQL` password then connect with it by the `terminal`.
After that run this command

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

you maybe get something similar

```
mysql> SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *EFBDB02467A8AB572944B873296089BB6607492C | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

s you can see, the plugin is auth_socket, which is causing the issue. Let’s update it to use the root password

```
'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'DO_PASSWORD_HERE';
```

Then flush the privileges to have the updates take effect.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then `exit;` and restart the MySQL `service mysql restart`

Everything should work now :)